# GET variable is &string(1) => "1"

Tags: php

I have a URL formatted like this:

```
https://chipperyman.com/commander/codes/check.php?type=check&group=w&cpu=63_char_string&version=27&group=1
```

However, when I use `var_dump($_GET);`, the `w` variable is set to `&string(1) => 1`. This is the full array:

```
array(4) { ["type"]=> string(5) "check" ["group"]=> &string(1) "1" ["cpu"]=> string(63) "63_char_string" ["version"]=> string(2) "27" }
```

Why is `$_GET['group']` not outputting correctly? When I try to `echo` it or use it in anything else (`.=`, etc) it is not treated as a w.

Comment: `group=1` overrides `group=w` since it comes last and you can't have 2 vars with the same name.

Comment: Oh, wow, I forgot I changed how the URL is supposed to be formatted... Oops. If you put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group=1` overrides `group=w` since it comes last and you can't have 2 variables with the same name.

It doesn't seem like you want this, but it is possible to have a `group` array using:

```
group[]=w&group[]=1
```

Comment: There is one exception to this and that is if the name has `[]` on the end to force it to an array. Duplicate values will be appended to an array.